# How I can integrate a ToolBar on my app with Kivy in Python?

Tags: python, kivy

I come to you today because I haven't been able to solve my problem for several days.

**What I'm trying to do:**

I want to create a ToolBar on the side of my application and make it available on all my screens. 
I tried several things but nothing came of it :( I'll leave you some of my code to see what I've done.

[I have deleted code here because I have change mine below]

Thank you in advance for your help and I am available for more information.
Have a good day!

NEWS:

I just tried to do what I was advised to do @Erik but I have an error when I start my program.

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/maelito/Desktop/tradingApp/app.py", line 1, in <module>
     from gui import window as w
   File "/Users/maelito/Desktop/tradingApp/gui/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
     app.run()
   File "/Users/maelito/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 799, in run
     self.load_kv(filename=self.kv_file)
   File "/Users/maelito/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 596, in load_kv
     root = Builder.load_file(rfilename)
   File "/Users/maelito/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 301, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "/Users/maelito/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 368, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
   File "/Users/maelito/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 392, in __init__
     self.parse(content)
   File "/Users/maelito/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 498, in parse
     self.execute_directives()
   File "/Users/maelito/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 452, in execute_directives
     kivy.lang.builder.Builder.load_file(ref)
   File "/Users/maelito/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 301, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "/Users/maelito/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 368, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
   File "/Users/maelito/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 392, in __init__
     self.parse(content)
   File "/Users/maelito/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 501, in parse
     objects, remaining_lines = self.parse_level(0, lines)
   File "/Users/maelito/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 605, in parse_level
     level + 1, lines[i:], spaces)
   File "/Users/maelito/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 664, in parse_level
     if current_property[:3] == 'on_':
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

So I share the new code with you too. (I had change nothing in screen1.kv and screen2.kv).

Window.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager


class ToolBar(GridLayout):
    pass


class Screen1(Screen):
    pass


class Screen2(Screen):
    pass


class WindowInterface(GridLayout):
    manager = ScreenManager()

    toolbar = ToolBar()
screen_1 = Screen1()
screen_2 = Screen2()

screen_1.add_widget(toolbar)
screen_2.add_widget(toolbar)

manager.add_widget(screen_1)
manager.add_widget(screen_2)

    def construct_toolbar(self):
        self.toolbar.add_buttons(self)


class Window(App):
    pass
```

window.kv

```
#:include gui/kv_files/screen_1.kv
#:include gui/kv_files/screen_2.kv
#:include gui/kv_files/toolbar.kv

#:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition

<WindowInterface>
    name: 'main_screen'
    BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"

            Label:
                text: "main screen"
            Button:
                text: "to screen 1"
                on_press: app.root.current = "screen_1"
            Button:
                text: "to screen 2"
                on_press: app.root.current = "screen_2"

    ScreenManager:
        Screen1:

        Screen2:

        ToolBar:
```

**toolbar.kv**

```
<Toolbar@GridLayout>
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size: 10,100

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: (1,1,1,1)
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
```

Thank you in advance. Maëlito!

Comment: Instead of having your root widget be your `ScreenManager`, have your root widget be a `Layout` object, like `GridLayout` or `FloatLayout`. Then in your `Layout` widget, just add your `ScreenManager` along with your `ToolBar`. Then when you switch screens, the toolbar will always be showing, since your screenmanager is only taking up a portion of your actual screen.

Comment: thank you @Erik, I tried that but I have a mistake. I posted a new answer with the new code. Thank you again

Comment: @MaëlLePetit I'll just leave this comment because in the question that you deleted, you left me a comment that I could not answer. To mark a question as a duplicate is not bad, we are only pointing out that your problem has been asked and has an answer. That is foreseen in SO because it saves us all time, because you no longer have to wait for someone to publish an answer and for me because I no longer spend time answering your question and that time I invest in another question, we all win.

Comment: @MaëlLePetit Marking as a duplicate does not imply that your question is bad, only that it has already been asked and there is an acceptable answer. And for example I can close this type of questions because I won the gold medal because I contribute a lot in questions that use this type of tags, I do not frame any question without meditating, I take the time to search (which is sometimes tedious ), analyze and if I see that it answers the OP question then I just do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal example of what you want accomplished. Hopefully you can see the inner workings of it and understand how to make it work for your application!

`main.py`

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

class ToolBarGrid():
    pass

class Screen1(Screen):
    pass

class Screen2(Screen):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def load_screen(self, new_screen_name):
        self.root.ids.screen_manager_id.current = new_screen_name

MainApp().run()
```

`main.kv`

```
GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    ToolBarGrid:
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager_id
        Screen1:
            id: "screen1"
            name: "screen1"
        Screen2:
            id: "screen2"
            name: "screen2"

<ToolBarGrid@GridLayout>:
    rows: 1
    Label: 
        text: "one"
    Label: 
        text: "two"
    Label: 
        text: "three"
    Label: 
        text: "four"

<Screen1>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text: "Screen 1"
        Button: 
            text: "Load screen 2"
            on_release: app.load_screen("screen2")

<Screen2>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text: "Screen 2"
        Button: 
            text: "Load screen 1"
            on_release: app.load_screen("screen1")
```

Comment: Hey! Personally I have a black screen when I test your code. Do you see anything else when you launch the app? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Are the name of the files `main.py` and `main.kv` like I specified? Perhaps you copy/pasted this code into files with different names?

Comment: just test.kv and test.py but it's the same for main

Comment: hmm.. if you used test.kv and test.py it wouldn't work because since my main app class is named `MainApp`, it looks for a file named main.kv -- but if you tried main.py and main.kv instead of test.py and test.kv and it still works that's something else

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that you are creating the toolbar inheriting from GridLayout in your .kv file (`Toolbar@GridLayout`), but you are missing the colon and indent since it is a class. It should look like:

```
<ToolBar@GridLayout>:
    BoxLayout:
        Your Code Here
```

Try that, and let me know what happens. Not sure if it's the complete issue, but just something I noticed in your code.